# Lines keep showing up in my graph. Why is this happening? How do I get rid of them?

Tags: matplotlib, bar-chart

```
role = DMGC_combined_df['Primary Role']

wins = DMGC_combined_df['wins']

plt.bar(role,wins)

plt.xlabel("Primary Role")

plt.ylabel("Wins")

plt.title('Wins per Primary Role in Top 4 Tiers')

plt.show()
```

#this is all my code is at this point, not sure why lines are showing up on my graph

[image]

Comment: The cause may be in the data, so why not post the data to the extent possible?

Comment: Possibly the x-values are repeated, and many bars are drawn with the same x-position.  Pandas or Seaborn plotting offer more options in such case.